# jquery each function not giving results?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have an AJAX call pulling a JSONP file, it will give me the data in the console, but when I try to put the results in an array: `topics`, I am getting an error.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/nbapulse/json/all.json',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "onDataLoaded",

        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            var topics = [];

            $.each(data, function(i, item){
                topics.push({
                    username: item.TopicName,
                    mentions: item.LastHourCount,
                    totalcount: item.TotalCount,
                    daycount: item.LastHourCount
                });
            });
            console.log(topics);
        $('#leader').tmpl(topics).appendTo('#top3');
        } 

    });
```

If I use `$.each(data.results, function(i, item)` it will display my jQuery template but all the data will be `undefined`. So I think the problem has to do with that?

Comment: *What* error are you getting? Is the response valid JSON **P**?

Comment: the console.log(data) gives me all the data i want from jsonp, so it is valid

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Jasper you can see it [here](http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/nbapulse/json/all.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(data.data, function(i, item){
```

This should do the trick, your object looks like this:

```
{
    data : [
        {},
        {},
        ...
    ]
}
```

So you needed to select the `data` property before iterating over the results.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YrJXG/

Answer (score 0):

Your $.each should look like this:

```
$.each(data.data, function(i, item){
                    topics.push({
                        username: item.TopicName,
                        mentions: item.LastHourCount,
                        totalcount: item.TotalCount,
                        daycount: item.LastHourCount
                    });
                });
```

Notice its "data.data" not "data".